# login() is not working at all - Django

Tags: django, authentication, django-views

I have a django app and I am trying to integrate the login system that they have within the framework. I have the following line of code:

```
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
login(request, user)
```

I am running this method right after I create a new user after the user signs up and creates an account. I know the authentication is going to be successfull because I just created the account and I know it is there. I am gettting the following error

```
login() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

In the documentation is says you pass in a request and user... so why is it not working. this is driving me crazy....

---

Here is the documentation on djangos websites:

```
login(request, user, backend=None)[source]¶
To log a user in, from a view, use login(). It takes an HttpRequest object and a User object. login() saves the user’s ID in the session, using Django’s session framework.

Note that any data set during the anonymous session is retained in the session after a user logs in.

This example shows how you might use both authenticate() and login():

from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def my_view(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
```

Here is my full signup method:

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            username = cd['username']
            password = cd['password']
            verify = cd['verify']
            email = cd['email']
            if password == verify:
                secure_password = make_password(password)
                user = User.objects.create(
                    username = username,
                    password = secure_password,
                    email = email,
                )
                user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
                if user is not None:
                    login(request, user)
                else:
                    return redirect('home')
            else:
                form = SignupForm()
                parameters = {
                    'form':form,
                }
                return render(request, 'users/signup.html', parameters)
    else:
        form = SignupForm()
        parameters = {
            'form':form
        }
        return render(request, 'users/signup.html', parameters)
```

Comment: Might be a long shot but did you define another function in your code called `login` which takes only one argument?

Comment: I absolutely hate my life right now. I feel retarded. I got the biggest dose of brain fart ever. I had a method called login which was where the user can login to his account by submitting the form... I changed the method in my views.py named login to user_login. it worked @stacksonstacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you havent declared any function with the same name as `login`

then

```
user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
```

you missed the request in the `authenticate`.

and if you have declared a function with the name `login` then change it to something else